# Incorrect data insertion in dynamic checkbox

Tags: jquery, sql

I have a problem on inserting dynamic checkboxes values into database. As shown below, if user were to select 'dinner', only the first letter of the selected box is inserted.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tnh7Y.png

Data insertion into tables

```
    foreach ( $_POST["dates"] as $index=>$date ) {
        $origin = $_POST["origins"][$index];
        $destination = $_POST["destinations"][$index];
        $cost = $_POST["costs"][$index];
        $meal = $_POST["meals"][$index];    

    //code for data insertion in other tables

    //Insert into meal table
    $sql_meal1 = sprintf("INSERT INTO tbl_meal (mealType) VALUES ('%s')",
        mysql_real_escape_string($meal));
        $result_meal1 = $db->query($sql_meal1);
        $inserted_meal_id1 = $db->last_insert_id(); 
    }
```

Jquery for dynamic checkboxes

```
 $(addMealBtn).click(function(e){   //dynamically adds new row to the Food & Lodging table
        e.preventDefault();
        if (mealCounter <= max_fields){     //check for maximum fields allowed
            var newMealRow = jQuery('<tbody><tr><td>'   //stores data of each field & merge as a new row
                + mealCounter + '</td>'
                + '<td><label><input id ="meals" type="checkbox" name="meals" value="breakfast" >Breakfast</label><br>' //wraps label around checkboxes to allow both of them clickable
                + '<label><input id ="meals" type="checkbox" name="meals" value="lunch" >Lunch</label><br>'                 
                + '<label><input id ="meals" type="checkbox" name="meals" value="dinner" >Dinner</label><br></select></td>'
                + '<td><a href = "#" class = "remove-meal-box"><img src = "DeleteRow.ico" height = "60" width = "60" align = "middle"/></a><br /></td></tr></tbody>'); 
            mealCounter++;

        jQuery('table.meal-details').append(newMealRow);    //append new row to the table
        var meal = $('#meals').val();
        if (mealCounter == max_fields){ //hides add field button when max of fields allowed is reached
            $(addMealBtn).hide();
        }
    }
    });
```

Comment: Most likely not a solution to your issue, but it **will** cause issues: Id must be unique! `id ="meals"` is set on at least 3 elements. Then `var meal = $('#meals').val();` has no idea what value to get.

Comment: Check if `$_POST["meals"]` is an array and not string

Comment: Also for checkboxes `name` should be `meals[]` if you want multiple selection.

Comment: @Tushar You're correct, a simple mistake was made. I was too focused on the SQL statement till I neglected the `meals[]` . However, it only inserts the first selection made if I were to tick all options given in the checkboxes. Any ideas to tackle this?

Comment: Use loop to get all selected check boxes